# Extracting Info from URL using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to take a URL and extract characters to multiple cells in Google Sheets.

The format of these URLs are:

```
https://www.sideshow.com/collectibles/{PRODUCT_NAME}-{PRODUCT_ID}
```

This is an example of the URL:

- https://www.sideshow.com/collectibles/marvel-scarlet-witch-sideshow-collectibles-300485

I'd like to extract the following to 2 different cells:

- Product ID: **300485** written to cell A1 as **300485**

   This 6 digit number will change on every URL but it will always be the last 6 characters of the URL
- Product Name: **marvel-scarlet-witch** written to cell B1 as **Marvel Scarlet Witch** (no dashes, proper case format)

The Product Name, `marvel-scarlet-witch`, will change with every URL but its position in the URL is constant.

I'm not sure if all this can be done in a single action or if two separate ones would be required.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also try (assuming string in D1)

```
=split(proper(substitute(regexreplace(D1, ".*\/(.*?)-side.*?([^-]\d+)$", "$2✓$1"), "-", " ")), "✓")
```

Change range to suit.

See [this link](https://regex101.com/r/FEpppt/1) for a brief explanation about the regular expression.

[image]

Comment: That's amazing!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string is in cell `C1`.

To extract **Product ID** from the given URL format, use the formula on `A1` cell:

```
=PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(C1,".*/(.*)-sideshow-collectibles"), "-", " "))
```

To extract **Product Name** from the given URL format, use the formula on `B1` cell:

```
=RIGHT(C1,6)
```